# Finding an expression for the sum of a power series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

I have the power series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}nx^{2n}=x^2-2x^4+3x^6\mp...$$
In the previous exercise I found by using the ratio test, the interval of convergence to be $(-1,1)$.

I want to find a "simple" expression for the series above on its interval of convergence.

My first thought: it kind of looks like the Maclaurin representation of $\cos x$.
$$\cos(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}x^{2n}}{(2n)!}=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}+\cdots$$

I could replace $\frac{1}{(2n)!}$ with $n$ (or can I?)
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}nx^{2n}$$ Which is close but no cigar. Might be something obvious I'm missing here. Notice the starting index is different as well.

Alternatively I could do something with the geometric series $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum x^n$?

Comment: This looks a lot like geometric series,try differentiating the geometric series

Comment: Hint: $x^{2n} = \left(x^2\right)^n$.

Comment: You hinting at the power series representation of $\sum [a_n](x-c)^n$ which gives $\sum [(-1)^{n-1}n]((x-0)^2)^n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the alternating geometric series:

$$\frac1{1+x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nx^n$$

And we have its derivative:

$$\frac{-1}{(1+x)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^nnx^{n-1}$$

Multiply both sides by $-x$ and let $x\mapsto x^2$ to finally get

> $$\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}nx^{2n}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: prove with induction that for the finite sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^m(-1)^{n-1}nx^{2n}={\frac { \left( -{x}^{2} \right) ^{m+1} \left(  \left( m+1 \right) {x}
^{2}-{x}^{2}+m+1 \right) }{ \left( {x}^{2}+1 \right) ^{2}}}+{\frac {{x
}^{2}}{ \left( {x}^{2}+1 \right) ^{2}}}
$$
is hold and compute then the Limit $$m$$ tends to infinity

Comment: One may likewise come up with this by following the finite form of my approach.  (+1) and have a nice day!

Comment: have a nice day too